# Analysis of updating vertex and one example?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, time-complexity, algorithm-analysis, trees

I see the following image on google:

[image]

And I want to find Amortized Cost for Updating of each vertex on Dijkstra algorithm. I have an answer $O(E/V)$. I'm get stuck it means at this answer we should used sorted array or binary heap for implementation? non of others get us this Amortized Cost?

Comment: Yes, and therefore you want something with $O(1)$ update. This is why Fibonacci heaps are the usual tool of choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Dijkstra's algorithm there are $|E|$ **update** operations and $|V|$ **remove_min** operations.

To implement the algorithm, we can employ different types of data-structures. Since you are looking for the best **update** cost per vertex, you can employ the *Fibonacci heap* or *Hash map* implementation since they give you the minimum **update** cost (as per the table mentioned in your question). Now, suppose you employ Fibonacci heap. Then, the total amortized **update** cost for Dijkstra's algorithm would be $|E| \cdot O(1) = O(|E|)$. Therefore, the amortized **update** cost per vertex is: $O(|E|/|V|)$.

---

These are the three main implementations of Dijkstra's algorithm:

1. Array Implementation (a.k.a. Hash Map as per your table): Update $O(1)$ and Remove_Min $O(|V|)$
2. Binary Heap Implementation (a.k.a. Hybrid Binary Heap as per your table): Update $O(\log |V|)$ and Remove_Min $O(\log |V| )$
3. Fibonacci Heap Implementation: Update Cost $O(1)$ and Remove_Min Cost $O(\log |V|)$

Note that Fibonacci Heap provides the best *update* cost and the best *remove_min* cost among these three options. Therefore, it is the best of both worlds. Hence, it is best for Dijkstra's algorithm and you can remember this implementation only.